# Adding texbox depending select option

Tags: javascript, vbscript, asp-classic

currently im developing simple application wth classic asp , when inserting data i need more textbox when user select on dropdown.

By default none of textbox show. If user chosse 1 there will be one textbox show, if 2 selected there will be 2 textbox verticaly and so on..

How can i achieve that ?

Comment: Where's your code?

Comment: Apologies  currently im login with smartphone, i cant provide code right now coz im on my way home, im just courius .

Comment: You are not going to get any meaningful answers on Stack Overflow if you don't provide code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it server side.
 So that every time they change the drop down it does a post back (form.submit on the onchange event) and then you can amend the text boxes in the ASP page.

That's probably not that great a user experience.

Alternatively, you could do it client side, so that every time they change the drop down,you capture the on change event and add the text boxes into the dom. You could do that using jquery or vanilla JavaScript.

You could also use a simple small library like knockout JS dynamically render the number of text boxes based on the drop downs selected value. But for one control, it's probably a lot to learn and an overkill. Good little library and helps keep your mark up clean.
http://knockoutjs.com

Comment: Actually you'd still need client side code for the first option, as JavaScript would need to post the form.

Comment: Yes, you are right, although, I had taken that bit for granted. Edited the post, for clarity.